Unable to Retrieve Session Using getServerSession in Next.js 15 API Route
I am experiencing an issue with retrieving the session using getServerSession in a Next.js 15 API route, while the same method works perfectly in server components (UI). Here is my setup:
import authOptions from "@/lib/auth";
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth";
import { NextRequest } from "next/server";

export async function GET(req : NextRequest) {
const session = await getServerSession(authOptions);
console.log("Session > ", session);
}

--Observations--

Session in Server Components: When using getServerSession in server components (UI), it successfully retrieves the session.

Session in API Route: In the API route, getServerSession always returns null.

Request Headers: The headers logged from the NextRequest object in the API route do not contain the required cookie header, which might explain why the session is not being retrieved.


--Things I Have Checked--

Middleware is not interfering with the API route.
authOptions configuration is valid and correctly set up with:
session.strategy = "jwt"
Proper secret and cookie settings in authOptions.cookies.
The API route is located in /app/api and not /pages/api.
The browser is sending the next-auth.session-token in the cookie (verified via Postman).

Any insights into what might be blocking getServerSession from accessing the session in API routes or how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated!
